# Limits of a piecewise functions

Tags: limits

[image]

I don't understand how to do this question. I've done a sketch, but wouldn't the limit as x tends to -2 from above be 2? I mean, it's on the actual point that it's tending too... However, I get the feeling that a is -3 from the question... But why? And how do I find b and c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If limit exists everywhere then, in particular it exists at $-2$.

If $\lim_{x\to-2^+}f(x)=-3$ we must have $\lim_{x\to-2}f(x)=-3$.  This implies that $$-3=\lim_{x\to-2^{-}}f(x)=\lim_{x\to-2^-}a=a,$$

where the second equality is because $f(x)=a$ for $x<-2$ close to $-2$.

To get $b$ check what happens at $x=3$.

At $x=3$ we need to compute the limit (not just compute the value of $f(3)$). Since the function is defined by pieces, it is likely to be simpler to compute lateral limits than just limit. Then let us look at

$$\lim_{x\to3+}f(x)$$ and $$\lim_{x\to3-}f(x)$$

We have that

$$\lim_{x\to3+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to3+}(2x+16)=22$$

and that $$\lim_{x\to3-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to3-}(x^2+bx+c)=9+3b+c$$
So, we must have $9+3b+c=22$. That is one equation relating $b$ and $c$.

But at $x=-2$ we didn't do the complete work. What about looking at $\lim_{x\to-2+}f(x)$?

Comment: I'm still confused... I don't think my teacher taught limits very well. At x=3, y=22. Is this to say that $9+3b+c=22$? Is that bit even needed?

Comment: @Jim That happens. Let me add some ideas.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I had a simultaneous equation but I had 4-2b+c=2 instead of =-3... This limits concept has yet to make complete sense to me, but I appreciate the help you have given :)